# How to get the same output using `sha3` by providing same address as input on nodejs?

Tags: sha3

I have following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Lottery {
  address public owner;
  bytes32 public hash;

  function Lottery() {        
    owner = msg.sender;
    hash = sha3(owner);
  }

  function get() constant returns (address, bytes32) {
    return (owner, hash);
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "0": "address: 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",
    "1": "bytes32: 0xb1591967aed668a4b27645ff40c444892d91bf5951b382995d4d4f6ee3a2ce03"
}
```

I want to obtain same `bytes32 hash` on the `nodejs` by providing same inputs as `"address: 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c".`

---

The javascript code I have:

```
module.exports = require('js-sha3');

Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("not connected");
    process.exit();
}

var owner = "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"; //given input on the smart-contract.

has=web3.sha3(owner);
console.log(hash)
```

Which prints:

```
0d87bf1419ed1b24bad65bbf117fcaded953923cb4eff8ca80bcde0aacb97357
```

That is not the same output I got on the solidity.

**[Q]** What should I do to get the same output using `sha3` by providing same address as input on nodejs?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the address first. Right now, you're computing the hash of the string representation of the address. Try this:

```
> web3.utils.sha3(new Buffer('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c'.substr(2), 'hex'))
'0xb1591967aed668a4b27645ff40c444892d91bf5951b382995d4d4f6ee3a2ce03'
```

(Note the `.substr(2)` to chop off the `"0x"` at the beginning of the address.)

**EDIT**

Another option:

```
> web3.utils.sha3(web3.utils.hexToBytes('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c'))
'0xb1591967aed668a4b27645ff40c444892d91bf5951b382995d4d4f6ee3a2ce03'
```

**EDIT 2**

The above was with `web3.js` 1.0.0-beta.x. For `web3.js` 0.x.x (I tested with 0.14.0):

```
> web3.sha3('0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', { encoding: 'hex' })
'b1591967aed668a4b27645ff40c444892d91bf5951b382995d4d4f6ee3a2ce03'
```

Comment: It says: `web3.utils.sha3`, `Cannot read property 'sha3' of undefined` when I just do `web3.sha3`it just returns "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" @smarx

Comment: What version of `web3` are you using?

Comment: How can I learn its version? I just did `npm install web3` hoping it will install its latest version. @smarx

Comment: I just added code for version 0.x.x to my answer, since I suspect that's what you're using.

Comment: (Oh, and to check which version you have, you can look in your `package.json`.)

Comment: Small important Q: How could I also do: `web3.sha3(10, owner)` on the nodejs side? thank you. @smarx

Comment: Solidity's `keccak256`/`sha3` concatenates its arguments. `10` will be considered a `bytes8`, so it will be padded to that size. Prepend your hex string with `0a`: `web3.sha3('0a' + 'ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', { encoding: 'hex' })` (and be careful to remove the intervening `"0x"`).

Comment: I asked over here maybe your answer might help others as well: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34423/what-should-i-do-to-get-the-same-output-using-sha3-by-providing-multiple-input @smarx