# What should I do to get the same output using `sha3` by providing multiple input on nodejs?

Tags: sha3

I have following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Lottery {
  address public owner;
  bytes32 public hash;

  function Lottery() {        
    owner = msg.sender;
    hash = sha3(10, owner);
  }

  function get() constant returns (address, bytes32) {
    return (owner, hash);
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "0": "address: 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",
    "1": "bytes32: 0x68690d4f19be42f79fab7837a1959281e0cb7c0a67c4c1efb7a1fcb008e5806e"
}
```

`sha3()` can get multiple input into each other.
I want to obtain same `bytes32 hash` on the `nodejs` by providing same inputs as some `uint` value and `"address: 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c".`as `sha3(uint, address)`.

---

I have followed following guide: (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/34420/4575)

The javascript code I have:

```
module.exports = require('js-sha3');

Web3 = require("web3");
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

if(!web3.isConnected()){
    console.log("not connected");
    process.exit();
}

var owner = "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"; //given input on the smart-contract.

hash = web3.utils.sha3( 10 + web3.utils.hexToBytes(owner) )
console.log(hash)
```

Which prints:

```
0xaf62552265611d75712f03dd8d2ae6efcb4c140dc8357ea015bd0572dd33ca82
```

That is not the same output I got on the solidity.

**[Q]** What should I do to get the same output using `sha3` by providing same uint, address as multiple parameter input on nodejs?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidity's `keccak256`/`sha3` concatenates its arguments. `10` will be considered a `bytes8`, so it will be padded to that size.

Prepend your hex string with `0a` (and be careful to remove the intervening `"0x"`):

```
> web3.sha3('0a' + 'ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c', { encoding: 'hex' })
'bbeea4a4cc90c8c1ea202ba19af7d6bd3e1059bd4529ae931ba6712c171ca1b4'
```

Comment: Basically, is `sha3(uint, address)` concatenate multiple inputs into each other as byte format? @smarx

Comment: Yes, in general `sha3(a, b, c, d, ...)` is the hash of the concatenation of all the arguments' binary representations. Be careful with types, though. If `10` is a `uint256`, then be sure to use 32 bytes for it instead of just 1.

Comment: If `10`is a `uint256`, should I define it as "0a" and 31 `0`s follows it? @smarx

Comment: No, 63 `0`s followed by an `a`. (Total length should be 32 bytes, big-endian, so 64 characters in hex with the least significant digit, the `a`, at the end.)

Comment: Is there also any tool for that on node. Assuming all decimal will be uint256. so tool that convert any decimal to 32 bytes? @smarx

Comment: `const number = 10; require('pad')(64, number.toString(16), '0')`

Comment: It says: `[length, text] = [text, length]; ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
` but thanks I got the idea. @smarx

Comment: `pad` says it requires Node 4.0+. Perhaps you're on an older version. (If so, you can use an older version of `pad`.)

Comment: I am actually on node `v4.2.6` @smarx

Comment: Okay, then I'm stumped. I've never used this module before; worked fine for me. :-) There are plenty of ways to pad a string, though!

Comment: I found a solution: `var num = 10;
var hex = '0x' + sprintf('%064s', num.toString(16));` it seems like correct. @smarx